# MVC 3 - Display collection of items in rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a collection that I'm displaying, like so:

```
@foreach (var employee in Model.Employees)
{
    <a href="#">@employee.Name</a>
}
```

This just displays everything in one long row. I'd like to display the collection in rows of 3, so that I have 3 items displayed, break to a new line, the next 3 items displayed, another break to a new line, and so on.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mystere Man is right, and I typically use list items as the semantic markup elements for collections of links.

```
<ul>
@foreach (var employee in Model.Employees)
{
    <li><a href="#">@employee.Name</a></li>
}
</ul>
```

Then use CSS styling to make your list look how you want it to use (no bullet points, etc.) If you make the `ul` have a fixed with, and each `li` inside of each have a width of 1/3 of that, then make the `li`s show up as inline blocks, that ought to give you what you're going for. ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StriplingWarrior/vQbAx/))

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with MVC, it's an HTML problem.  You need to render HTML to make it do what you want.  Look at the rendered output.

Typically you would wrap rows in divs or other elements in order to create the semantic markup you want.

Answer (score 0):

not using css, here's a simpleish way of doing this.

```
@{ var i = 0; }
@foreach (var employee in Model.Employees)
{
    @{ i++; } 
    <a href="#">@employee.Name</a>
    @if(i%3 == 2)
    {
        <br/>
    }
}
```